# ASP.Net Core Application Redirects to http in cookie based login

Tags: asp.net-core

I am accessing the site with https but it is redirecting to HTTP login page, which parameter is forcing to HTTP, below is my code

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/denied");
        });
```

I cannot use HttpsRedirection middleware in this project because of some restriction.
Do I need to any param to stop redirecting to HTTP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to know how and where you host and run your app.

Comment: Hi @FeiHan,
The application is hosted in AWS

Comment: If you run app on local, does this issue occur?

Comment: Hi @FeiHan,
No, It is not happening in my local. It is only happening in my production server